# Drag and play hangs up while using PHP Pseudo Streaming script

Tags: php, apache

I want to implement pseudo streaming mp4 with PHP to my website so I can authenticate each user for watching videos.

Here is the source code I refered to 
http://www.tuxxin.com/php-mp4-streaming/

```
<?php

$file = 'video360p.mp4';
$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');

$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

header('Content-type: video/mp4');
//header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

$c_start = $start;
$c_end   = $end;

list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    exit;
}
if ($range == '-') {
    $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
}else{
    $range  = explode('-', $range);
    $c_start = $range[0];
    $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
}
$c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
    header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
    exit;
}
$start  = $c_start;
$end    = $c_end;
$length = $end - $start + 1;
fseek($fp, $start);
header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);

$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
    $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
}
set_time_limit(0);
echo fread($fp, $buffer);
flush();
}

fclose($fp);
exit();
?>
```

But the problem is when I drag and play an video quickly, The 206 request will hang up. At the same time, all ajax requests to that PHP server will pending, too. I need to restart Apache service, or close and reopen whole browser, or even wait until the request failed and reload the page(wait about 100 minutes).

This problem will only happen when I'm using Chrome and Firefox in Window, I didn't see this issue on Mac.

Chrome Version: 42.0.2311.135 (64-bit) in Mac
                42.0.2311.152m in Windows 7

PHP Version:    PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.7 (cli) (built: Mar 16 2015 20:47:39)

Apache2:        Apache/2.4.7

Thanks

Comment: This question should not be closed. It should be answered.